# How to get Angular model data back to a large number of DOM elements?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, data-binding

I'm working on a calendar app, and for convenience, I'm rendering the (largish) DOM in a Sinatra app. Whenever you click a day in the calendar, that day is toggled as "flagged" in the model.

This is pretty straight forward without much code:

```html
<body ng-controller="CalendarCtrl" ng-click="toggle_day($event)">
```

and in the `CalendarCtrl`:

```js
$scope.toggle_me = function($event) {
  var target = angular.element($event.target);
  if (target.attr("data-date")) {
    $scope.toggle(target.attr("data-date"));
  }
}

$scope.toggle = function(date) {
  $scope.days[date] = 1 - ($scope.days[date] | 0);
}
```

What I have a problem with is getting the data back to the DOM elements. I'd like to add a class "active" to all days that are flagged in the model.

I could do this with a tedious:

```html
<td data-date="20130101" ng-class="'active' if day is marked">1</td>
```

(never mind the pseudo code in the `ng-class` expression) but **I'd have to do this for 365 days.** Ugh.

I sense that a custom directive could solve this, but I don't know how to proceed. Are there any other solutions to this problem?

Comment: Why don't you let Sinatra render the ng-class too?

Comment: @Narretz That's what I would do! But it bloats the DOM with 365 additional ng-classes, and I had hoped for a more generic solution. You see, I don't need 365 handlers to get it into in the model, so having 365 bindings for the other direction just feels wrong to me...